# Using taskmanager (or something like it) to check processes running on another computer

Tags: windows-98

OK, here is the situation.  I have an old computer running windows 98.  It has recently started booting to a blank screen. It gets past the win98 logo screen, but instead of displaying the user name/password screen, it just shows a blank black screen.  It will show up on the network at this point.  This started after a game my kids were playing locked up and I had to hard boot it.  Tried booting in safe mode.  It boots into safe mode fine, but when I reboot and let it come up normal, same thing happens.  Tried using msconfig to disable just about everything in the startup, but that doesn't help.  I would like to use something like taskmanager to check which programs are running on that computer.  Any ideas?

Extra info:

Below is from the bootlog.txt file.  Any ideas on what might be causing the problem?

```
[00153E3C] Loading Device = C:\WINDOWS\HIMEM.SYS
(Logo disabled)
[00153EA0] LoadSuccess    = C:\WINDOWS\HIMEM.SYS
[00153EA0] Loading Device = C:\WINDOWS\DBLBUFF.SYS
[00153EA0] LoadSuccess    = C:\WINDOWS\DBLBUFF.SYS
[00153EA0] Loading Device = C:\WINDOWS\IFSHLP.SYS
[00153EA0] LoadSuccess    = C:\WINDOWS\IFSHLP.SYS
[00153EA0] (Safe boot)
[00153F00] Loading Vxd = VMM
[00153F01] LoadSuccess = VMM
[00153F01] Loading Vxd = vmouse
[00153F01] LoadSuccess = vmouse
[00153F01] Loading Vxd = configmg
[00153F01] LoadSuccess = configmg
[00153F01] Loading Vxd = vwin32
[00153F01] LoadSuccess = vwin32
[00153F01] Loading Vxd = vfbackup
[00153F01] LoadSuccess = vfbackup
[00153F01] Loading Vxd = vcomm
[00153F01] LoadSuccess = vcomm
[00153F01] Loading Vxd = C:\WINDOWS\system\VMM32\ifsmgr.VXD
[00153F02] LoadSuccess = C:\WINDOWS\system\VMM32\ifsmgr.VXD
[00153F02] Loading Vxd = C:\WINDOWS\system\VMM32\ios.VXD
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = C:\WINDOWS\system\VMM32\ios.VXD
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = vfat
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = vfat
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = vcache
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = vcache
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = vcond
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = vcond
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = int13
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = int13
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = vxdldr
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = vxdldr
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = vdef
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = vdef
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = dynapage
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = dynapage
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = reboot
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = reboot
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = vsd
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = vsd
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = parity
[00153F03] LoadSuccess = parity
[00153F03] Loading Vxd = biosxlat
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = biosxlat
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = vmcpd
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = vmcpd
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = vkd
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = vkd
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = vdd
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = vdd
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = ebios
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = ebios
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = vtdapi
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = vtdapi
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = vmpoll
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = vmpoll
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = VPICD
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = VPICD
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = VDMAD
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = VDMAD
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = VTD
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = VTD
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = V86MMGR
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = V86MMGR
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = PAGESWAP
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = PAGESWAP
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = DOSMGR
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = DOSMGR
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = SHELL
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = SHELL
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = UDF
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = UDF
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = VCD
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = VCD
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = NTKERN
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = NTKERN
[00153F04] Loading Vxd = VPD
[00153F04] LoadSuccess = VPD
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VMM     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VMM     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VCACHE  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VCACHE  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VPICD   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VPICD   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VTD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VTD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VWIN32  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VWIN32  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VXDLDR  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VXDLDR  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = NTKERN  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = NTKERN  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = CONFIGMG
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = CONFIGMG
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = IOS     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = IOS     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = PAGEFILE
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = PAGEFILE
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = PAGESWAP
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = PAGESWAP
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = PARITY  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = PARITY  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = REBOOT  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = REBOOT  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = EBIOS   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = EBIOS   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VDD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VDD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VSD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VSD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VCD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VCD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VMOUSE  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VMOUSE  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VKD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VKD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VPD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VPD     
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = INT13   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = INT13   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VMCPD   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VMCPD   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = BIOSXLAT
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = BIOSXLAT
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = DOSMGR  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = DOSMGR  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VMPOLL  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VMPOLL  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VCOMM   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VCOMM   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VCOND   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VCOND   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VTDAPI  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VTDAPI  
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = VDMAD   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VDMAD   
[00153F06] SYSCRITINIT  = V86MMGR 
[00153F06] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = V86MMGR 
[00153F07] SYSCRITINIT  = VFAT    
[00153F07] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VFAT    
[00153F07] SYSCRITINIT  = VDEF    
[00153F07] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VDEF    
[00153F07] SYSCRITINIT  = UDF     
[00153F07] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = UDF     
[00153F07] SYSCRITINIT  = IFSMGR  
[00153F07] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = IFSMGR  
[00153F07] SYSCRITINIT  = VFBACKUP
[00153F07] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = VFBACKUP
[00153F07] SYSCRITINIT  = SHELL   
[00153F07] SYSCRITINITSUCCESS  = SHELL   
[00153F09] DEVICEINIT   = VMM     
[00153F09] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VMM     
[00153F09] DEVICEINIT   = VCACHE  
[00153F09] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VCACHE  
[00153F0A] DEVICEINIT   = VPICD   
[00153F0A] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VPICD   
[00153F0A] DEVICEINIT   = VTD     
[00153F0A] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VTD     
[00153F0C] DEVICEINIT   = VWIN32  
[00153F0C] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VWIN32  
[00153F0C] DEVICEINIT   = VXDLDR  
[00153F0C] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VXDLDR  
[00153F0C] DEVICEINIT   = NTKERN  
[00153F0C] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = NTKERN  
[00153F0C] DEVICEINIT   = CONFIGMG
[00153F0C] Starting Unknown (HTREE\ROOT\0)
[00153F0C] Started Unknown (HTREE\ROOT\0)
[00153F0C] Enumerating Unknown (HTREE\ROOT\0)
[00153F0C] Enumerated Unknown (HTREE\ROOT\0)
[00153F0C] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = CONFIGMG
[00153F0C] DEVICEINIT   = IOS     
[00153F0D] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\apix.vxd
[00153F0E] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\apix.vxd
[00153F0E] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\atapchng.vxd
[00153F0E] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\atapchng.vxd
[00153F0E] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\cdfs.vxd
[00153F0E] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\cdfs.vxd
[00153F0E] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\cdtsd.vxd
[00153F0E] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\cdtsd.vxd
[00153F0E] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\cdvsd.vxd
[00153F0F] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\cdvsd.vxd
[00153F0F] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\disktsd.vxd
[00153F0F] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\disktsd.vxd
[00153F0F] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\diskvsd.vxd
[00153F0F] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\diskvsd.vxd
[00153F0F] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\necatapi.vxd
[00153F10] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\necatapi.vxd
[00153F10] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\scsi1hlp.vxd
[00153F10] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\scsi1hlp.vxd
[00153F10] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\torisan3.vxd
[00153F11] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\torisan3.vxd
[00153F11] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\voltrack.vxd
[00153F11] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\voltrack.vxd
[00153F11] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\smartvsd.vxd
[00153F12] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\smartvsd.vxd
[00153F12] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\rmm.pdr
[00153F12] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\rmm.pdr
[00153F12] Dynamic load device  C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\bigmem.drv
[00153F13] Dynamic load success C:\WINDOWS\system\IOSUBSYS\bigmem.drv
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = IOS     
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = PAGEFILE
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = PAGEFILE
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = PAGESWAP
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = PAGESWAP
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = PARITY  
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = PARITY  
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = REBOOT  
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = REBOOT  
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = EBIOS   
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = EBIOS   
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = VDD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VDD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = VSD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VSD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = VCD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VCD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = VMOUSE  
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VMOUSE  
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = VKD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VKD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = VPD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VPD     
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = INT13   
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = INT13   
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = VMCPD   
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VMCPD   
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = BIOSXLAT
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = BIOSXLAT
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = DOSMGR  
[00153F13] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = DOSMGR  
[00153F13] DEVICEINIT   = VMPOLL  
[00153F14] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VMPOLL  
[00153F14] DEVICEINIT   = VCOMM   
[00153F14] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VCOMM   
[00153F14] DEVICEINIT   = VCOND   
[00153F14] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VCOND   
[00153F14] DEVICEINIT   = VTDAPI  
[00153F14] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VTDAPI  
[00153F14] DEVICEINIT   = VDMAD   
[00153F14] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VDMAD   
[00153F14] DEVICEINIT   = V86MMGR 
[00153F14] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = V86MMGR 
[00153F14] DEVICEINIT   = VFAT    
[00153F14] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VFAT    
[00153F14] DEVICEINIT   = VDEF    
[00153F14] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = VDEF    
[00153F14] DEVICEINIT   = UDF     
[00153F14] DEVICEINITSUCCESS   = UDF     
[00153F2A] INITCOMPLETE = VMM     
[00153F2B] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VMM     
[00153F2B] INITCOMPLETE = VCACHE  
[00153F2B] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VCACHE  
[00153F2B] INITCOMPLETE = VPICD   
[00153F2B] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VPICD   
[00153F2B] INITCOMPLETE = VTD     
[00153F2B] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VTD     
[00153F2B] INITCOMPLETE = VWIN32  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VWIN32  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = VXDLDR  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VXDLDR  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = NTKERN  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = NTKERN  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = CONFIGMG
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = CONFIGMG
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = IOS     
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = IOS     
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = PAGEFILE
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = PAGEFILE
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = PAGESWAP
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = PAGESWAP
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = PARITY  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = PARITY  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = REBOOT  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = REBOOT  
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = EBIOS   
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = EBIOS   
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = VDD     
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VDD     
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = VSD     
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VSD     
[00153F2C] INITCOMPLETE = VCD     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VCD     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VMOUSE  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VMOUSE  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VKD     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VKD     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VPD     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VPD     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = INT13   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = INT13   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VMCPD   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VMCPD   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = BIOSXLAT
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = BIOSXLAT
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = DOSMGR  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = DOSMGR  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VMPOLL  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VMPOLL  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VCOMM   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VCOMM   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VCOND   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VCOND   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VTDAPI  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VTDAPI  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = voltrack
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = voltrack
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = RMM     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = RMM     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = BIGMEM  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = BIGMEM  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VDMAD   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VDMAD   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = V86MMGR 
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = V86MMGR 
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VFAT    
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VFAT    
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VDEF    
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VDEF    
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = UDF     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = UDF     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = IFSMGR  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = IFSMGR  
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VFD     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VFD     
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = VFBACKUP
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = VFBACKUP
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETE = SHELL   
[00153F2D] INITCOMPLETESUCCESS = SHELL   
Initializing KERNEL
LoadStart = SYSTEM.DRV
LoadSuccess = SYSTEM.DRV
LoadStart = KEYBOARD.DRV
LoadSuccess = KEYBOARD.DRV
LoadStart = MOUSE.DRV
LoadSuccess = MOUSE.DRV
LoadStart = VGA.DRV
LoadSuccess = VGA.DRV
LoadStart = MMSOUND.DRV
LoadSuccess = MMSOUND.DRV
LoadStart = COMM.DRV
LoadSuccess = COMM.DRV
LoadStart = GDI.EXE
LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\GDI32.DLL
LoadStart = GDI.EXE
LoadSuccess = GDI.EXE
LoadStart = GDI.EXE
LoadSuccess = GDI.EXE
LoadStart = GDI.EXE
LoadSuccess = GDI.EXE
LoadStart = GDI.EXE
LoadSuccess = GDI.EXE
LoadSuccess = C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\GDI32.DLL
LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\vgasys.fon
LoadSuccess = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\vgasys.fon
LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\vgafix.fon
LoadSuccess = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\vgafix.fon
LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\vgaoem.fon
LoadSuccess = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\vgaoem.fon
LoadSuccess = GDI.EXE
LoadStart = USER.EXE
LoadStart = DDEML.DLL
LoadSuccess = DDEML.DLL
LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\USER32.DLL
LoadStart = USER.EXE
LoadSuccess = USER.EXE
LoadStart = USER.EXE
LoadSuccess = USER.EXE
LoadStart = USER.EXE
LoadSuccess = USER.EXE
LoadStart = USER.EXE
LoadSuccess = USER.EXE
LoadStart = USER.EXE
LoadSuccess = USER.EXE
LoadSuccess = C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\USER32.DLL
LoadStart = COOL.DLL
LoadSuccess = COOL.DLL
Init = KEYBOARD
InitDone = KEYBOARD
Init = Mouse
Status = Mouse driver installed
InitDone = Mouse
Init = 
LoadStart = DISPLAY.drv
LoadSuccess = DISPLAY.drv
InitDone = DISPLAY
Init = Display Resources
InitDone = Display Resources
LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\MARLETT.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\MARLETT.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\SSERIFE.FON
LoadSuccess = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\SSERIFE.FON
LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\LUCON.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\LUCON.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TAHOMA.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TAHOMA.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\tahomabd.ttf
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\tahomabd.ttf Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIAL.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIAL.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIALBD.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIALBD.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIALBI.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIALBI.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIALI.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIALI.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COUR.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COUR.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COURBD.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COURBD.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COURBI.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COURBI.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COURI.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COURI.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TIMES.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TIMES.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TIMESBD.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TIMESBD.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TIMESBI.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TIMESBI.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TIMESI.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\TIMESI.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\WINGDING.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\WINGDING.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\SYMBOL.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\SYMBOL.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIBLK.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\ARIBLK.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COMIC.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COMIC.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COMICBD.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\COMICBD.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\IMPACT.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\IMPACT.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\VERDANA.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\VERDANA.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\VERDANAB.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\VERDANAB.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\VERDANAI.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\VERDANAI.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\VERDANAZ.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\VERDANAZ.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\WEBDINGS.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\WEBDINGS.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\phonetic.fon
LoadSuccess = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\phonetic.fon
LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\verdref.ttf
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\verdref.ttf Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\grgaref.ttf
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\grgaref.ttf Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\refspec.ttf
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\refspec.ttf Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\msref1.ttf
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\msref1.ttf Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\msref2.ttf
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\msref2.ttf Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\HUDSON2.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\HUDSON2.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadStart = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\HUDSONB2.TTF
LoadFail = C:\WINDOWS\fonts\HUDSONB2.TTF Failure code is 0016

LoadSuccess = USER.EXE
LoadStart = MSGSRV32.EXE
LoadSuccess = MSGSRV32.EXE
Init = Final USER
InitDone = Final USER
Init = Installable Drivers
InitDone = Installable Drivers
Init = TSRQuery
InitDone = TSRQuery
[00153F6E] Starting Unknown (HTREE\RESERVED\0)
[00153F6E] Started Unknown (HTREE\RESERVED\0)
[00153F6F] Enumerating Unknown (HTREE\RESERVED\0)
[00153F6F] Enumerated Unknown (HTREE\RESERVED\0)
```

Comment: This really should be on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booting in safe mode uses the Windows generic display driver, and apparently that works.
The conclusion is that something broke the video driver, so it needs re-installing.
If you haven't kept the installation CD, you might still be able to find the driver on google.

You might try in safe mode to set the display driver to a generic type.
Anyway, check all the display options, whatever they may be on Win98.

Comment: Reinstalling the video drivers did it.  Have a bounty.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad this worked out for you.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me with [**PSTools**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) from Sysinternals, using `pslist` to get the process list and `psexec` to execute `pslist` on the remote system:

```
psexec \\servername -u username -p password -c pslist.exe -accepteula
```

-c will copy the executable to execute (here pslist.exe) on the remote system.
-accepteula accepts automatically the license agreement that is displayed when you run for the 1st time one of the tools.

Comment: Tried that but all I keep getting is the error message:"Couldn't access [servername]:
The network path was not found. Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on [servername]."

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running Service Manager (start > run > services.msc) and "[menu] Action > Connect to anoher computer" ? This doesn't show all running processes but if you're lucky the problem process will be in there and can be disabled or set to manual start....

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at Windows 98 in a while, so this may be incorrect...

Try finding the user profile that is loaded at startup, and renaming the folder to profile_old. Then reboot and see if it recreates a new profile. If it works, you should be able to copy any files that you need from the renamed folders.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 98? Eek!

Does this also happen if you boot into `Safe Mode with Networking`? You said you tried `Safe Mode`, but the Networking edition can be a useful diagnostic.

I'm more scared that you're still run 98, though, personally :)

Comment: It's on a computer that I let my 7,6 and 3 year old play on for precisely this reason.  My "real" computer is most definitely not on 98.  I upgraded to ME a long time ago ;)

Comment: maybe I should go back to cheering for 98? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) when in Safe Mode and see if there's anything that doesn't belong.  But I don't even know if it works on Windows 98.